# Core Data query on iOS

Tags: ios, core-data

I have:

AT <<-->> ST <<-->> CT <-->> D

I want to get all AT entities that are related to D.

Is it possible? If so, how would I go about getting them?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that you have an instance of `D`, called `d`, and that each object has a sensibly named relationship, try:

```
[d.ct.st valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.at];
```

This navigates the initial single relationship to `CT`, then gets the set of `ST` object, asks each for its `AT` objects and generates the distinct collection of the result.

Comment: Key-Value Collection Operators are a very powerful and underutilized feature in Cocoa / Cocoa Touch, so +1 for bringing them up. More examples can be found here: http://nshipster.com/kvc-collection-operators/

Comment: One thing I notice that is not what I really wanted as a result is that the result of that doesn't put the AT entities alone in the result, but they're grouped in dictionaries. I can't just loop through the AT entities once I have the result. Not sure how to handle that yet. I thought this would have given you an array of AT entities just like a normal fetch request would. So, I am not sure if this really answers the question like I wanted it to.

Comment: Try @distinctUnionOfArrays instead

Comment: Thanks to Wain for pointing me in the right direction I then read the documentation (http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html), so I found that what I needed to use is "distinctUnionOfSets" instead. That puts the entities in one array just like I would get from a standard fetch request. So, using the "distinctUnionOfSets" is what ended up really work for me. thank you.